# Splitting columns in a DF based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a df with multiple columns. I need to separate one of those columns into two columns, one based on ID and another one based on the description.

for example on row 34:

```
data['cpv'][34] = '45232460-4 - Obras de saneamento'
```

I would need to obtain column `cpvid` to be `45232460-4` and column `cpvdescription` to be `Obras de saneamento`.
This would be fairly easy to do with a string split.

However there are some some cases where

```
df['cpv'][45] = '45112500-0 - Movimento de terras | 45232411-6 - Construção de condutas para águas residuais | 45232423-3 - Construção de estações de bombagem de águas residuais'
```

Meaning there are multiple ID's and multiple descriptions on the same row. I was wondering if there is any efficient way to split the columns based on more than one condition. Meaning the first condition would be '*-*' (under brackets for space) and another condition for '|'.

Could anyone please assist? I'm still a newbie I tried to find some similar posts however none seem to fit my desired output.

Thanks!

Comment: describe what is the desidered output

Comment: The desired output would be df['cpvid] = '45232423-3' ; df[cpvd] = 'Movimento de terras' df[cpvid1] = "45232411-6 " ; df[cpvd1] = 'Construção de condutas para águas residuais' ; and so forth. Not sure if this is possible without a complex function, if this needs a really complicated function. Do not worry, I'll try to manually split them, however the df was over 300k lines

Comment: Would there be possible to instead of having multiple columns for cpvid and cpvdescription have just the two columns (cpvid and cpvdescription) and create new rows in the cases when there are multiple ID's and descriptions on the same row in the original df? The information in the other columns on these rows will be replicated on the new rows.

Comment: That would also work for this required project! Do you have an idea on how to implement it? It would greatly save me a lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the long format you can make use of a string split combined with the `explode` method (I've create a dummy `df` based on your data):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cpv':['45232460-4 - Obras de saneamento', '45112500-0 - Movimento de terras | 45232411-6 - Construção de condutas para águas residuais | 45232423-3 - Construção de estações de bombagem de águas residuais'],
    'val':[1,2]
})

df = df.assign(cpv=df.cpv.str.split(r' \| ')).explode('cpv')

df = pd.concat([df, df.cpv.str.split(r' - ', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'cpvid', 1:'cpvdescription'})], axis=1).drop('cpv', axis=1)

print(df)

val       cpvid                                     cpvdescription
0    1  45232460-4                                Obras de saneamento
1    2  45112500-0                                Movimento de terras
1    2  45232411-6        Construção de condutas para águas residuais
1    2  45232423-3  Construção de estações de bombagem de águas re...
```

If you want the wide format you can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cpv':['45232460-4 - Obras de saneamento', '45112500-0 - Movimento de terras | 45232411-6 - Construção de condutas para águas residuais | 45232423-3 - Construção de estações de bombagem de águas residuais'],
    'val':[1,2]
})

cpv_df = pd.DataFrame(df.assign(cpv=df.cpv.str.split(r' \| ')).cpv.to_list())

df = pd.concat([df]+[cpv_df[col].str.split(r' - ', expand=True).rename(columns={0:f'cpvid_{col}', 1:f'cpvdescription_{col}'}) for col in cpv_df], axis=1).drop('cpv', axis=1)

print(df)

   val     cpvid_0     cpvdescription_0     cpvid_1  \
0    1  45232460-4  Obras de saneamento        None   
1    2  45112500-0  Movimento de terras  45232411-6   

                              cpvdescription_1     cpvid_2  \
0                                         None        None   
1  Construção de condutas para águas residuais  45232423-3   

                                    cpvdescription_2  
0                                               None  
1  Construção de estações de bombagem de águas re...
```

Comment: Anders Källmar, thank you so much for the help! for the long format  andusing the string split combined with the explode method. works perfectly for my desired output. Thank you so much! 

However when I try to run the second code for the wide format between columns I get an error saying "TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()"

Comment: I guess it relates to the format of your data, so it is hard for me to replicate. What line in the code causes the error and is it possible for you to try it on a small sample of your data to make sure the code works overall? If this works, try finding the particular rows that causes the error.